# Visual Studio: x86/x64 Properties Macro

Tags: visual-studio

I'm looking for a [Visual Studio Build Configuration Macro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx) of the form 'x86' or 'x64'. I am aware of `$(Platform)` but, this seems to give me 'Win32' or 'x64'.

Does anyone know of a macro that will give 'x86' instead of 'Win32'? I'm interested in Visual Studio 2015 in particular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use $(PlatformShortName) bro..

Comment: Add more description

Comment: That seems to be the correct property to use, but it seems not documented, see https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/issues/806

Answer (score 1):

The `$(PlatformShortName)` macro evaluates to the value you are expecting for those platforms.

| Platform | `$(Platform)` | `$(PlatformShortName)` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Win32 | `Win32` | `x86` |
| x64 | `x64` | `x64` |

This is also briefly documented on Microsoft Docs under [Common macros for build commands and properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=msvc-140).

You can also check its value for other platforms by using the "Macros" tab when editing a property. This will display the evaluated values for different macros under the current configuration:

[image: A screenshot of the Macros panel, inspecting "$(PlatformShortName)" which has the value "x64"]